# What type of visa do I need for short term voluntary work in Turkey?

Tags: visas, turkey, volunteering, homestay

I am from the UK and planning on traveling through Europe into west Asia. I would like to volunteer while staying at home-stays for brief periods e.g one or two weeks.

For example - one website: http://www.thetravellerslounge.co.uk/visas/ says I can **travel** 90 days in Turkey **without** a visa, so could I also live at a home-stay using '[workaway](https://www.workaway.info/)' or '[helpx](https://www.helpx.net/)' and volunteer there without getting any visa? Or is that classed as *working?*

Comment: have you made contact with some workaway host?

Comment: Yes I have already had an offer from a family in Turkey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a UK citizen and a visitor, you're required to obtain an electronic [visa](http://www.emirates.com/ca/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=GB&NV=United+Kingdom&DC=TR&DV=Turkey&h=bb8da96f6dffe322d8fefffd429fad3d4b1d2aa) that allows you 90 days in Turkey. This should largely cover the time of your stay, which you mentioned was a couple of weeks.

Turkey defines work, the criteria for a work visa, as being a paid activity.
It doesn't have a specific [volunteering](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/general-information-about-turkish-visas.en.mfa) visa, and you'll note that [work](http://www.invest.gov.tr/en-US/investmentguide/investorsguide/comingtoturkey/Pages/HowToGetAWorkPermit.aspx) visas require detailed documents about your payment, employer and specific [wage](http://www.invest.gov.tr/en-US/infocenter/publications/Documents/work-permit-criteria-EN.pdf) requirements. So if you're not being paid, that makes you ineligible for a work visa.